# parsing line python

Tags: linux, python

```
   self.filename = d.get('filename', '/var/www/html/data/reading.txt')
    syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_INFO, "pond: using %s" % self.filename)
    self.bind(weewx.NEW_ARCHIVE_RECORD, self.read_file)

def read_file(self, event):
    try:
        with open(self.filename) as f:
            #value = f.read()
            f.seek(-8, os.SEEK_END)
            line = f.readlines()[-1]
            value = line.split(',')
        syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_DEBUG, "pond: found value of %s" % value)
        event.record['ccwatt'] = float(value[0])
        event.record['cctemp'] = float(value[1])
    except Exception, e:
        syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_ERR, "pond: cannot read value: %s" % e)
```

The above python will read the last line in txt file and add a new archive record for example:

```
123,54
```

How do I alter it to add an archive record when there is only one value available to record. Obviously the `split(',')` will not work on one value

```
123
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick conditional should do the trick here:

```
            if "," in line:
                value = line.split(',')
            else:
                value = line
```

Added to your code:

```
    self.filename = d.get('filename', '/var/www/html/data/reading.txt')
    syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_INFO, "pond: using %s" % self.filename)
    self.bind(weewx.NEW_ARCHIVE_RECORD, self.read_file)

def read_file(self, event):
    try:
        with open(self.filename) as f:
            #value = f.read()
            f.seek(-8, os.SEEK_END)
            line = f.readlines()[-1]
            if "," in line:
                value = line.split(',')
            else:
                value = line
        syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_DEBUG, "pond: found value of %s" % value)
        event.record['ccwatt'] = float(value[0])
        event.record['cctemp'] = float(value[1])
    except Exception, e:
        syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_ERR, "pond: cannot read value: %s" % e)
```